# Sharing files and folders between Ubuntu 12.04 and Virtual Box as a test platform

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

How do I share files between Ubuntu 12.04 and virtual box? I would like to use VB as a test platform for downloads etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install what is called [Virtualbox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).

After you finish installing that, you will be able to share files between the two systems using the Virtualbox "shared folders" setting.